# Prestashop Change description error on validation

Tags: prestashop

I want to change description this error:

There is 1 error
address1 is invalid.
« Back

I want to change from "is invalid" to "is invalid. Address field must not contain @, #, % and other"

**I searched file, whose show errors. (./themes/default-bootstrap/errors.tpl)**

```
    {if isset($errors) && $errors}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>{if $errors|@count > 1}{l s='There are %d errors' sprintf=$errors|@count}{else}{l s='There is %d error' sprintf=$errors|@count}{/if}</p>
        <ol>
        {foreach from=$errors key=k item=error}
            <li>{$error}</li>
        {/foreach}
        </ol>
        {if isset($smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER) && !strstr($request_uri, 'authentication') && preg_replace('#^https?://[^/]+/#', '/', $smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER) != $request_uri}
            <p class="lnk"><a href="{$smarty.server.HTTP_REFERER|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|secureReferrer}" title="{l s='Back'}">&laquo; {l s='Back'}</a></p>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/if}
```

and **Validation  (./js/validate.js)**

```
 function validate_isAddress(s)
{
    var reg = /^[^!<>?=+@{}_$%]+$/;
    return reg.test(s);
}
```

and Address.tpl  (./themes/default-bootstrap/address.tpl)

```
<p class="required text">
                <label for="address1">{l s='Address'}</label>
                <input  class="text" data-validate="{$address_validation.$field_name.validate}" type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value="{if isset($smarty.post.address1)}{$smarty.post.address1}{else}{if isset($address->address1)}{$address->address1|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{/if}">
    <sup>*</sup>
</p>
```

But I did not find the file in which to change the description of the error

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/f6715aba1653f51c0ee97187c57ac281.png    On image 3 errors. i want 1 error×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change all of the error statements in the backoffice of Prestashop
Go to your Prestashop backoffice:

**Localisation->translations**

in the select option box, select "error message translations" there you can adjust all of the error messages in the whole website.

It's better to do this instead of changing some core Prestashop files.

[image: Screenshot of Prestashop translation options]

**error message adjustment screen**

[image: Another Prestashop 1.6 screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I changed description of the error for each field separately? (phone, address, name and other?)

Comment: Updated my answer with another screenshot. But you can change all of the error field messages. In case your site has multiple languages you have to adjust it for every language.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/f6715aba1653f51c0ee97187c57ac281.png    On image 3 errors. i want 1 error